# how many tiles from city can be worked?

Tags: civilization-6

Is there a limit to the number of tiles a city can work? I've noticed that I can purchase and use tiles several spaces away from my city. How far can I go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tiles up to three away from the city center can be selected to be worked.

Additionally, the number of citizens is the limiting factor for worked tiles. Let's assume a newly settled city has one citizen. Even if you buy tiles for that city, only one tile will be worked since the city only has one citizen.

Answer (score 5):

Do note, however, that tiles that are not being worked on can provide adjacency for worked tiles. So buying/improving land that you cannot immediately(or in case of 4 space away, ever) work on can be beneficial, thou the return is significantly reduced.
Furthermore, strategic/luxury resource does not need to be worked on to provide you the resource, so improvements on those are good anytime and any distance away.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately, this would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: "or in case of 4 space away, ever)" - can you elaborate? Why ever?

Comment: because you cannot work on tiles 4 spaces away, ever. Well, unless there is mod to change that

Answer (score 3):

Just like in Civ V, the maximum distance that can be worked is 3 tiles away from the city center.